# can not send int to respond in ktor

Tags: kotlin, backend, ktor, ktor-client

I'm trying to send int response but get an error but when I use both as a string then response get successfully.

```
 post("/employee") {
        call.respond(mapOf("hey" to "Hey","if" to 1))
    }
```

**LOGCAT**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Serializing collections of different element types is not yet supported. Selected serializers: [kotlin.String, kotlin.Int]
at io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.SerializerLookupKt.elementSerializer(SerializerLookup.kt:45)
at io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.SerializerLookupKt.guessSerializer(SerializerLookup.kt:29)
at io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.KotlinxSerializationBase.serialize$ktor_serialization_kotlinx(KotlinxSerializationBase.kt:34)
at
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass different types in response "yet" like mentioned in stacktrace. As a workaround you can pass `1` as string or create custom class for this response and serialize it to json and send it like that

Comment: as you mention I had tried with the custom class as well, but still get the same response

Comment: But have you serialized it to json?